# Can't convert undefined to object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Error: cant convert undefined to object : `this.page[1]=100;`. It is already defined, whats wrong?
[image]

```
var sheepclass ;
(function($) {
    sheepclass = function(handler){
        var $div = $('div');            
        this.handler = $.extend({
            'sizes': 'thin', 
            'eat': 'grass',
            'color': 'white',
            'page':[],
            myalert: function() {
                myconsole();
                function myconsole() {
                    this.page[0] = 100; 
                    console.log(this.page[0]);
                }
            },
            myalert2: function() {
                this.myalert();
            }
        },handler);
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    var blacksheep = new sheepclass({'color':'black'});
    blacksheep.handler.myalert2();
})
```

Comment: Why do you need to wrap that in a document ready handler? Your code involves zero DOM manipulation. So many code smells here.

Comment: classic issue of understanding the scope of `this`

Comment: That `myalert` section looks dodgy.
Why are you adding a function there that executes a function, then initializes that function?

Comment: I am making a jquery plugin that's allow people to new an object outside, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a `that` variable for `this`

```
    var sheepclass ;
    (function($) {
        sheepclass = function(handler){
            var $div = $('div');            
            this.handler = $.extend({
                'sizes': 'thin', 
                'eat': 'grass',
                'color': 'white',
                'page':[200,300],
                myalert: function() {
                    var that = this;
                    myconsole();
                    function myconsole() {
                        that.page = that.page || []
                        that.page[0] = 100; 
                        console.log(that.page[0]);
                    }
                },
                myalert2: function() {
                    this.myalert();
                }
            },handler);
        }
    })(jQuery);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var blacksheep = new sheepclass({'color':'black'});
        blacksheep.handler.myalert2();
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, passing the context by using `that` helper variable

```
var sheepclass ;
(function($) {
    sheepclass = function(handler){
        var $div = $('div');
        var that = this;
        this.handler = $.extend({
            'sizes': 'thin', 
            'eat': 'grass',
            'color': 'white',
            'page':[],
            myalert: function() {
                myconsole();
                function myconsole() {
                    that.handler.page[0] = 100; 
                    console.log(that.handler.page[0]);
                }
            },
            myalert2: function() {
                this.myalert();
            }
        },handler);
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    var blacksheep = new sheepclass({'color':'black'});
    blacksheep.handler.myalert2();
})
```

Comment: You don't need to have the closure variable all the way out there. You can use the `this` from inside `myalert`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `myconsole` `this` is not equal to your object, but refers to `Window` instead. Therefore `this.page` is `undefined` -- the value you index into `page` with does not make a difference.

You have to change the call to:

```
myconsole.call(this);
```

Comment: yes,it works, but strange, then I have change all my functions become *.call(this)... I have many functions.. why have to use these weird methods. its getting strange

Comment: @FatDogMark: It's not clear why you have many nested functions. You could of course capture `this` into another variable (e.g. `that`) and write `that.page` instead of `this.page`, but it would still mean you have to find all references to `this` and change them to `that`. There is no easier way to do what you are doing, which means that what you are doing is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this code seems to be pointless. The `document.ready` handler is unnecessary, since there is no DOM manipulation, as is the IIFE. Your code could be reduced to:

```
var sheepclass = function(handler){
    this.handler = $.extend({
        'sizes': 'thin', 
        'eat': 'grass',
        'color': 'white',
        'page':[],
        myalert: function() {
            var context = this;
            function myconsole() {
                context.page[0] = 100; 
                console.log(context.page[0]);
            }
            myconsole();
        }
    },handler);
}

var blacksheep = new sheepclass({'color':'black'});
blacksheep.handler.myalert();
```

Notice also that having a method that does nothing but invoke another method is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Becouse "this" is referred to myconsole function.

Try this:

```
var sheepclass ;
(function($) {
    sheepclass = function(handler){
        var $div = $('div');    
        **var page = this.page;**
        this.handler = $.extend({
            'sizes': 'thin', 
            'eat': 'grass',
            'color': 'white',
            'page':[],
            myalert: function() {
                myconsole();
                function myconsole() {
                    **page**[0] = 100; 
                    console.log(**page**[0]);
                }
            },
            myalert2: function() {
                this.myalert();
            }
        },handler);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what's up with the asterisks ?

Comment: asterisks is bold style, sorry.